# Laravel Passing Controller data to View

Tags: laravel-5

Trying to pass data generated in controller to view.

Route in web.php

```
Route::get('person', ['uses'=>'PersonController@index']);
```

Controller app/Http/Controllers/Person.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {

    $age = 35;
    $height = 68;
    $weight = 102;

    // Calculate rest of BPX values
    $BPXVals = [];
    // Actual Weight
    $BPXVals['actualWeight']          =   $weight;
    $BPXVals['actualWeight2']         =   pow($weight, 2);
    $BPXVals['actualWeight3']         =   pow($weight, 3);
    $BPXVals['weightLN']              =   log($weight);

    return View::make('person.index', ['BPXVals'=>$BPXVals]);

  }
}
```

View in Resources/Views/index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      {{  $BPXVals  }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Getting the following error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 721:
Class App\Http\Controllers\PersonController does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong in defining my route or linking the route to the controller and/or view?

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload` in console from project root, bacause I do not see any error in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to changing the app/Http/Controllers/Person.php  to app/Http/Controllers/PersonController.php

Comment: Thx, I changed the name of the controller file to PersonControoler.php and now get the following error: ErrorException in helpers.php line 533:
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /path/to/resources/views/person/index.blade.php)

Comment: you can not print an array as you did `{{  $BPXVals  }}`. You need to print the values as `{{  $BPXVals['weightLN']  }}`

Comment: That worked! So I need to refer to array indexes in the view and cannot just dump an array like in Twig. That's what I needed to know. Thanks.